# Is Abstract dummy interfaces a recommended programming habit in Fortran?

Tags: pointers, fortran, intel-fortran

In my code I have different subroutines that need to be executed on a certain order depending on what inputs the user specify. For example, we could have

```
  do TIMELOOP = 1, n 

      if(userinput_1) then 
         call routine_1(..) 
         call routine_2 (..)
        etc etc 
      elseif (userinput_2) then 
        call routine_3(....)
        call routine_1(....)
      endif 

  enddo
```

A solution I have been using to avoid all these ifs is by using a an array of  pointers to procedures

```
 type ptr_proc 
     procedure(A_INT), pointer :: proc 
 end type 

 type(ptr_proc), allocatable :: ptr(:)
```

The issue is that Fortran requires the pointer `proc` to always point to procedures with same interface defined as the `A_INT`. There is no way I can do this as routine_1, routine_2 etc are very different.

I overcome this by defining the following magical interface

```
 abstract interface 
    subroutine A_INT 
    end subroutine 
 end interface
```

In other words, it has an empty interface. The routines with empty interfaces are basically wrappers for routine_1, routine_2 etc.

So as an example, a wrapper for routine_1 could be:

```
 subroutine WRAP_ROUT_1 
 use MOD_FOR_ROUT_1 
 call ROUTINE_1( ...) ! - I insert the (inputs, outputs) here which I have from the use statement
 end subroutine
```

Then, during my initialisation I point all my pointers to the corresponding wrapper procedures.

```
   if(userinput_1) then 
      ptr(1)% proc => WRAP_ROUT_1 
      ptr(2)% proc => WRAP_ROUT_2 
      etc  etc. 
   elseif ... 
   endif
```

Then my timeloop looks like

```
    do TIMELOOP = 1, n 
      do i = 1 , size(ptr) 
         call ptr(i)% PROC 
      enddo
  enddo
```

It works, however, I fear whether this could lead to potential problems/danger. My question really boils down to the consequenes of using such a programming practice in Fortran.

Comment: This really looks opinion based. The very concept of "recommended" is often opinion based. Recommended by whom?

Comment: The first solution seems much easier to understand. Why do you want to implement something  less clear and more complicated ?

Comment: It is legitimate to have `procedure(), pointer :: proc`.  If you want to compare approaches you should probably include that one.

Comment: "In other words, it has an empty interface."  No: the interface isn't empty, it's an interface for a subroutine with no arguments

Comment: Thanks for the correction regarding the empty interface statement. All right, I think I wanted to be sure that it is firstly legitimiate to do pointer to procedure of subroutines with no arguments.

Comment: Yes, it's fine to have a pointer to a subroutine with no arguments.  That's different (very) from a `procedure()`, though.  Which is worth considering.

Comment: If `n` is large and the user input happens only once per entire loop (not per loop cycle), then it would make sense to bring the if-block out of the loop and write separate loops for each if-block, otherwise, the first style in your question seems more intuitive, in your special problem. I have seen occastions where the latter (procedure pointer or pointer in general) is an absolute necessity to write clean concise code.